# facebook web app, getting error 'The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the code from the facebook app developer site. I tried it and I am getting the following error :

```
"The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF"
```

The code used is as follows :

```
  <?php 

   $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
   $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
   $my_url = "YOUR_URL";

   session_start();
   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     echo("Hello " . $user->name);
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }

 ?>
```

From the code its obv that for some reason, $_REQUEST['state'] != $_SESSION['state']. Can somebody please explain why this is happening. I am also a PHP amateur.

Thank u :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SDK, much easier.

This code gets the user data and serializes it, and throws to the database, i know its not perfect but have a look. I'm going to edit this when i get some free time, then i recommend encoding the users data as JSON, not as base64 serialized, because it will be easier to do query searches in the future.

```
    <?php
        require 'facebook.php'; // USE FACEBOOK PHP SDK

        // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => 'APPID',
          'secret' => 'APPSECRET',
        ));
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Get User ID
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        /* We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
           If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
           Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
           token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook. */

        if ($user) {
          try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            // these are the graph calls
            $dt = $facebook->api('/me');
            $lk = $facebook->api('/me/likes');
          } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
          }
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Handler for Login Status
        // With the LoginURL, user the 'scope' to ask for permissions
        if ($user) {
          $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        } else {
          $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "email,user_birthday,user_likes,user_work_history,user_location,user_education_history"));
        }
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ?>
        <?php if (!$user): header ('Location:'.$loginUrl.''); //CHECKS IF USER IS LOGGED IN
        else: 

 // Do Something here. This next bit of code shows what comes out of those calls.
      echo "<pre>"; 
      print_r($dt);
      echo"</pre>";

      echo"<br/><br/>";

      echo "<pre>"; 
      print_r($lk);
      echo"</pre>";

      endif
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do realize that this problem is already 2 months old but I have a similar issue using the Heroku code. I'm not fully done debugging it yet but I've noticed that the output of

```
session_id();
```

changes in IE after a refresh but remains the same in Chrome suggesting that the session gets lost in IE. Obviously, the state of the session will be blank in IE and you receive the CSRF error while it works fine under Chrome.

If someone can shed more light on this I would be grateful. I'll keep updating this answer as I find out more as to what specifically is causing the issue in IE and how to solve it.

[edit]Duh. It's a cookie issue. My IE had blocked coockies (including session cookies) while Chrome didn't. I got the idea after reading http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/294235. I'm unsure of the workaround though. I'll keep this updated as I find out more. Any input from others is welcome![/edit]

[edit-2]Alright, as promised here's the solution. You need to activate P3P like so:

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

Add this to the top of your code where you're using your session(s). I found the solution at [Session Lost on IE Facebook App iFrame](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7205332/session-lost-on-ie-facebook-app-iframe)

For the sake of completeness, here's the code I'm using (look at the login method)-

```
<?php

/**
 * This class provides Facebook specfic utility functions that you may use
 * to build your app.
 */


require_once('AppInfo.php');
require_once('utils.php');

class FBUtils {

  /*****************************************************************************
   *
   * The content below provides some helper functions that you may wish to use as
   * you develop your app.
   *
   ****************************************************************************/

  /**
   * GETs graph.facebook.com/$target, and returns it as decoded JSON
   * To learn more about the Graph API, visit:
   *  'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/refererence/api'
   *
   * @return graph api content of $target
   */
  public static function fetchFromFBGraph($target) {
   return self::curl('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $target);
  }

  /**
   * Uses FQL (Facebook Query Language) to return the result of $query with the
   * access-token $token.  FQL is used to process more complex requests that the
   * graph API does not directly expose.  For more information, visit
      'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql'
   *
   * @return Facebook Query result for $query
   */
  public static function fql($query, $token) {
    $query = urlencode($query);
    return self::curl("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=$query&format=json&access_token=$token");
  }

  /**
   * Helper function
   * @return the JSON decoded results of curling $url
   */
  public static function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
  }

  /**
   * Authenticates the current viewer of the app, prompting them to login and
   * grant permissions if necessary.  For more information, check the
   * 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/'
   *
   * @return app access token if login is successful
   */
  public static function login($redirect) {
    $app_id = AppInfo::appID();
    //echo "app id: $app_id <br>";
    $app_secret = AppInfo::appSecret();
    //echo "app secret: $app_secret <br>";
    $home = AppInfo::getHome();
    //echo "home: $home <br>";
    // Scope defines what permissions that we are asking the user to grant.
    // In this example, we are asking for the ability to publish stories
    // about using the app, access to what the user likes, and to be able
    // to use their pictures.  You should rewrite this scope with whatever
    // permissions your app needs.
    // See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/
    // for a full list of permissions
    $scope = 'user_likes,user_photos,user_photo_video_tags,publish_stream';
    //session_start();
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
    // If we don't have a code returned from Facebook, the first step is to get
    // that code
    if (empty($code)) {
        //echo "test"; exit();
      // CSRF protection - for more information, look at 'Security Considerations'
      // at 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/'
      $state = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
      setcookie(
        AppInfo::appID() . '-fb-app',
        $state,
        $expires = time()+3600,
        $path = "",
        $domain = "",
        $secure = "",
        $httponly = true); 
        $_SESSION[AppInfo::appID() . '-fb-app'] = $state;
        echo session_id(); exit(); // debugging output
      // Now form the login URL that you will use to authorize your app
      $authorize_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=$app_id" .
"&redirect_uri=$home&state=" . $state . "&scope=$scope";
      // Now we redirect the user to the login page
      echo("<script> window.location.href='" . $authorize_url . "'</script>");
      return false;
    // Once we have that code, we can now request an access-token.  We check to
    // ensure that the state has remained the same.
    } else 
    {
        echo $_REQUEST['state']."|"; echo $_SESSION[AppInfo::appID() . '-fb-app']; exit(); // debugging output
    if ($_REQUEST['state'] === $_COOKIE[AppInfo::appID() . '-fb-app']) {
      $ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "client_id=$app_id&redirect_uri=$home&client_secret=$app_secret" .
        "&code=$code&scope=$scope");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      // Once we get a response, we then parse it to extract the access token
      parse_str($response, $params);
      $token = $params['access_token'];
      return $token;
    // In the event that the two states do not match, we return false to signify
    // that something has gone wrong during authentication
    }}
    //else {
    //  echo("States do not match.  CSRF?");
    //  return false;
    //}
  }
}
```